# Java project file organization: new packages vs subfolders

Tags: java, ant, netbeans-7

I apologize in advance for the naive nature of the question but I'm new to Java development and I've been looking for an answer for a while now.  Here goes...

I would like to organize my Java project profiles according to purpose or function.  In other words, I would like to have a java project organized like this

- Application

  - FXML
  - JDBC
  - GUI
  - Core Logic

This organization immediately suggests a folder with subfolders.  My problem is that this paradigm is used by the NetBeans IDE for subpackages rather than simple subfolders.

The reason this is problematic for me is that I would like to use member access and visibility restrictions and still operate among my project files.  Although this particular project isn't going to be an API, I still have no wish to make all my classes and class members public.

In particular, if I create a ...

```
protected final Client getClientByIndex(int idx) { ... }
```

... in a class file in the JDBC folder, I would ideally like to still be able to regard this file as being part of the same package and therefore accessible to the other classes in my project.  However, because NetBeans uses the subfolder paradigm to describe subpackages only, it doesn't appear that this is possible unless I'm missing something.  The Java Specification about protected access is very clear on this:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own 
>   package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another 
>   package.

So ... if I want to organize my project files into subfolders I must either do so as subpackages and either make everything public or subclass (not ideal for me), or ... I must just put all my project files that I wish to have in the same package into the same folder (not ideal either).

Is there an IDE out there that will enable the distinction at build time between a project subfolder and a folder that is intended as a subpackage?  It seems to me that this kind of distinction ought to be possible via appropriate descriptors in build files.  Is there an IDE that allows this?  Is this possible with custom Ant files only?

Comment: Have you ever used Maven? It has native support in Netbeans and you can organize multi-module projects that match what you are looking for, pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

youre describing a multi-module project - a project composed of multiple modules where each module (normally) compiles into its own *.jar.
all IDEs support this, in one way or another (in intellij idea you adda module by selecting file-->new module), but the best way to create such a project would be to use a build system that supports modules and have your IDE of choice import the project.
[maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a very popular "build system" that can easily be used to create a multi-module porject. see [chapter 6](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) of the maven book for further details.